# What is the least expensive method to get a row count for a SQL Query?

Tags: sql, mysql

When writing a query for paging on a web page what is the least expensive method to get a total row count? Is there a way to do this without running a query twice - one for the total and the next for the limit?

Using MySQL

Example: (I want to know if there is a less expensive way)

Get Count

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
```

Get Paging

```
SELECT mycolumns FROM table LIMIT 100
```

How can I get the total count without running 2 queries.

Comment: try pre-counting the table size and store the value and run a background process to update the values from time to time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you an additional column called `Count` in each row that contains the total number of rows:

```
SELECT mycolumns, (select count(*) from table) as Count 
FROM table 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Is this more efficient than the two queries?

Comment: This will be more efficient than separate queries as you are only making one call to the database from your application.

Comment: Although this question is marked with the tags SQL, and MySQL, the above solution will only work in some SQL variants, such as MySQL. Other variants will require a GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 4):

You can run the first query with the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option, and then run this:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Comment: Excellent - Is this less expensive then the 2 queries?

Comment: I can't guarantee that it will be *less* expensive than 2 queries in all cases, but it certainly shouldn't be *more* expensive. The comparison will depend on lots of factors: storage engine(s), size of table, columns being selected, where clause, index vs. full scan, etc.

Comment: In short, if you are worried about performance you may want to do some testing with your specific data.

Answer (score 0):

> select count(*) from *tablename*

Is the most efficient way to get the number of rows in table `tablename`

Comment: "Is there a way to do this without running a query twice"

Comment: why would you have to run this (or mine) query twice?

Comment: Because one for the count and the second for the paging (limit) so that only x amount of rows are returned to the page. You have problem seen the 1 | 2 | 3 ... Last at the bottom of pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(1) as counter from *table_name*
```

this is slighter better than using `count(*)` as your avoiding checking all the columns in the table.

Comment: Good idea for the first query but how do I combine the queries

Comment: there is no difference between count(*) and count(1): http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156159920245 http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156151916789

Comment: This answer getting upvoted makes me very sad. There is so much material out there that proves beyond a shadow of a doubt that count(1) is equivalent to count(*). There is no reason for this rumor to persist. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1